# MessageMediaDocument not return file_id ( like bots )

Tags: telethon

I use this code

```
msg = await client.get_messages('me', limit=1, offset_id=0)
```

But print(msg) not show to me file_id like bots:

```
BQACAgQAAxkBAAK9_F8sa5j8iJQ845yxMdgYieRXRQwpAALrBwACzo2RU...
```

How I can get file_id for medias?

Answer (score 0):

[`client.get_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.get_messages) returns a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [`Message`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message). Your `print(msg)` will print this entire list. If you only want the [`Message.file`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.file) (and within that the [`File.id`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.file.File.id)), you should [access that field](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-field):

```py
messages = await client.get_messages(...)

print(messages[0].file.id)
```

Note that only bots can use this file ID to send it at a later time, and you don't need it to download the file at all.

Note that this file ID may not be valid forever.